# Returning a more specific class

Tags: c#, casting

I would appreciate some feedback on my design of a few classes to query the [Trakt.tv API](http://trakt.tv/api-docs).

```
public abstract class TraktQuery
{
    private const string baseUrl = "http://api.trakt.tv/";
    private const string apiKey = "[API key here]";

    protected abstract string QueryUrl { get; }
    protected abstract List<string> QueryParameters { get; }
    protected abstract TraktResponse ParseResponse(string response);

    public TraktResponse PerformQuery()
    {
        //exception handling removed for brevity
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        string url = baseUrl + QueryUrl + "/" + apiKey + "/" + string.Join("/", QueryParameters);
        string response = webClient.DownloadString(url);
        return ParseResponse(response);
    }
}

public class TraktQueryEpisodeSummary : TraktQuery
{
    private string _showName;
    private int _season;
    private int _episodeNumber;

    public TraktQueryEpisodeSummary(string showName, int season, int episodeNumber)
    {
        _showName = showName;
        _season = season;
        _episodeNumber = episodeNumber;
    }

    protected override string QueryUrl
    {
        get { return "show/episode/summary.json"; }
    }

    protected override List<string> QueryParameters
    {
        get
        {
            List<string> paramters = new List<string>();
            paramters.Add(_showName);
            paramters.Add("" + _season);
            paramters.Add("" + _episodeNumber);
            return paramters;
        }
    }

    protected override TraktResponse ParseResponse(string response)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TraktResponseEpisodeSummary>(response);
    }

public class TraktResponseEpisodeSummary : TraktResponse
{
    public TraktShowInformation show { get; set; }
    public TraktEpisode episode { get; set; }
}
```

Currently `TraktResponse` is an empty abstract class but I'll probably add to it soon.

This code is then used as follows:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        TraktQueryEpisodeSummary query = new TraktQueryEpisodeSummary("House", 1, 1);
        TraktResponseEpisodeSummary summary = (TraktResponseEpisodeSummary)query.PerformQuery();

        Console.WriteLine("Title: " + summary.show.title);
        Console.WriteLine("Poster image: " + summary.show.images.poster);
        Console.WriteLine("Genres: " + string.Join(", ", summary.show.genres));
        Console.WriteLine("Episode name: " + summary.episode.title);
        Console.WriteLine("Overview: " + summary.episode.overview);
    }
}
```

What makes me think my design isn't quite right is that I have to cast from `TraktResponse` to the more specific `TraktResponseEpisodeSummary` in order to access the information I need. What I would like to do is make `TraktQueryEpisodeSummary.ParseResponse()` return a `TraktResponseEpisodeSummary` instead of a `TraktResponse` however I'm aware that C# doesn't support return type covariance which I think is what this is.

Are my concerns well-founded or not? Is there a better design that avoids this casting or is it perfectly normal and acceptable?

Comment: Could you use generics to turn PerformQuery into PerformQuery<T>() where T: TraktResponse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dreza has outlined the correct approach (the same used in `IComparable<T>`). You can make your class generic, with a type constraint:

```
public abstract class TraktQuery<TResponse> where TResponse : TraktResponse
```

And change every occurence of `TraktResponse` to `TResponse`:

```
protected abstract TResponse ParseResponse(string response);
```

and

```
public TResponse PerformQuery()
{
    //...
}
```

Then, your deriving class can be defined as

```
public class TraktQueryEpisodeSummary : TraktQuery<TraktResponseEpisodeSummary>
{
    //...
    protected override TraktResponseEpisodeSummary ParseResponse(string response)
    {
        //...
    }
    //...
}
```

Voila, no cast necessary:

```
TraktResponseEpisodeSummary summary = query.PerformQuery();
```

---

Further suggestions:

- Use collection and object initializers, for instance in the overridden `QueryParameters`:

  ```
   return new List<string> {_showName, _season.ToString(), _episodeNumber.ToString()};
  ```
- Or turn them into an `IEnumerable<string>` and use an iterator block:

  ```
  protected override IEnumerable<string> QueryParameters
  {
      get
      {
          yield return _showName;
          yield return _season.ToString();
          yield return _episodeNumber.ToString();
      }
  }
  ```
- Be careful when concatenating strings to form a URL like this:

  ```
  string url = baseUrl + QueryUrl + "/" + apiKey + "/" + string.Join("/",QueryParameters);
  ```

  It might be better to

  1. Use the [`Uri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and/or [`UriBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder.aspx) class
  2. Put the first three parts into an sequence, then call [`IEnumerable<T>.Concat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx) and finally `string.Join`
  3. There's probably some even better options.

Comment: That's a great way to solve the problem. Extra bonus points for the other points of advice as well. Thanks very much.